# ASP.Net Does NOT accept <appsettings> tag

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. I added following code to solve Validation Controls problem:

```
<appsettings>  
       <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms">  
</add></appsettings>
```

But creating new bugs with adding this. Getting Error "HTTP Error 500.19" with this information:

---

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
The configuration section 'appsettings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.
Error Code: 0x80070032

---

My web.config content is simply this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->

<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

  </system.web>

   <appsettings>  
       <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms">  
   </add></appsettings>  

</configuration>
```

I searched the web and didn't find a specific solution for this issue. And as I saw in related articles such errors may have many reasons. I don't know which one causing mine.

Answer (score 4):

XML is case sensitive. You are looking for `<appSettings>`, not `<appsettings>`:

```
<appSettings>  
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
</appSettings>
```

You can make the `add` element self-closing, but that is just a little nice syntactic sugar that isn't required.

More documentation about the `appSettings` element [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx).

Comment: I didn't know this. You saved me a lot of time buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

Your add tag should be self-terminating, but as vcsjones points out, your issue is likely case sensitivity of `<appSettings>` (not `<appsettings>`)

```
   <appSettings>  
       <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms"/>  
   </appSettings>
```

Comment: I should mention that my first code works fine if I use appSettings instead of appsettings but if I make a little modification and replace the </add> tag and put it beside the middle line it gives error. (This is strange)
But if I make it the way you suggest, it works...